# Comparing hastable with equals

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

I have a rather silly question, but  I was wondering whether it is achievable to compare inputs of a hash map with `equals()` before the compiler would do it for us.  I am attempting to get a count of the number of times I've entered a duplicate key-value pair into the map.

I have written some code but I don't know how to implement the `equals()`. Any idea?

```
Map<String, String> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    newMap.put("aaa", "bbb");
    newMap.put("ccc", "ddd");
    newMap.put("eee", "fff");
    newMap.put("aaa", "bbb");
    System.out.println(newMap.size());

    for(String item : newMap.keySet()){
        System.out.println(item + " "+newMap.get(item));

    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Your question is a little unclear.

Comment: Well, I am actually trying to get a counter of how many times I have entered the same key-value pair.

Comment: Do you want the structure to do this for you? (It doesn't - you would need to write your own.) A `Map` by definition will only store one value per key, so if you add some value with the key `"aaa"` and then add a second value with the same key, the first is _replaced_. You can (in your own code) use `newMap.containsKey()` to see if the key already exists in the `Map`.

Comment: @CraigOtis actually I want to count how many entries with the same key were entered. I thought of using equals() somehow to compare with the Map.

Comment: The Map won't keep track of that for you, nor will it store more than one value for the same key. If you enter two values with the same key, then examine your map, it will only have one of them.

Comment: If you intended to store multiple values for the same key, it's very common to have a structure of `Map<String, List<String>>` instead.

Comment: @CraigOtis so can you suggest me a way to do this?

Comment: You can't implement equals yourself on these built in types. At least provide an example with the usage of the equals, even if not implemented.

Comment: @sayidjetzenden To write a data structure that maintains multiple values for the same key? Or that tells you how many times a specific key was added to the map?

Comment: What has `equal`s got to do with tracking the count of `put` calls?

Comment: I think the best way of achieving what you're trying to do is everytime you add a pair key,value check if the key contains in the map as @CraigOtis said and then add +1 it in a variable like `counterInsertedKeyRepeat++`

Comment: @weston I thought there's actually a way to compare an entry with the Map, so I thought of equals. CraigOtis I want something to count how many times I have tried to enter the same key-val pair. I will try to implement Craig's solution as Fernando stated.

Comment: @Weston Actually, technically you could extend a class just to override its `equals` or any other method, but that doesn't really help in this situation.

Comment: Also, this is the third time I have seen this exact same question just recently. There are probably other instances of it I've missed. As I commented on another one of them, this is probably a homework assignment that these people all have due soon.

Comment: @Aaron:  If you could show us where those other, similar questions are, we could close them as a duplicate of this.  The fact that they *may* be homework questions is immaterial, since this isn't all that uncommon to want to do during professional development anyway.

Comment: @Makoto I have specifically been avoiding linking the similar questions precisely because I'm >90% sure they are homework questions, and I'm trying to avoid handing out the silver platter which others keep doing. These are basically "I want **The Code**" type of questions. Or, even if they aren't, the answers we are getting for them are. Homework questions aren't off topic (do we still have a homework tag?), but I think The Code handout question/answers are. I'm not complaining since I accidentally give those answers sometimes too, but I'm still calling it out. It's a minor issue though.

Comment: @Aaron:  Not that I disagree, but in general, I would assume good faith on the part of the asker and answerers in this scenario.  If you *do* see answers which simply support "gimme the code", feel encouraged to downvote liberally.  However, it's still valuable to link those questions or vote to close as a duplicate so that this sort of information is at least contained to one place.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with a single map, but you can do something with an abstraction of it.

Here is an example compatible with Java 8; using two maps, we are able to keep full tabs of when a specific key is entered into the map and increment based on the key.  Assume this is defined in a separate class.

```
Map<K, V> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Map<K, Integer> newMapOccurrences = new HashMap<>();

public void put(K key, V value) {
    newMap.put(key, value);
    newMapOccurrences.put(key, newMapOccurrences.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
}

public Integer getCount(K key) {
    return newMapOccurrences.getOrDefault(key, 0);
}
```

If you want to be sure to track key-value pairs, that's a bit trickier since it's not really recommended to use a map as a key entry. Furthermore, since maps key off of the key anyway, trying to keep track of both wouldn't be the best idea, and you may wind up with an off-count.  However, I do offer an idea in the form of a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>>` which *may* get you started in the right direction in that endeavor; however, I leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to keep a Map that tracks the how many times you have called `map.put()` for a given key of type K.

If you want the put operation to automatically track this for you, you can have a new Map class that extends `LinkedHashMap`. Then, the put operation will keep track of insertion count e.g.

```
public class KeyCountMap<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V> {
  private HashMap<K, Integer> keyCountMap;

  public KeyCountMap() {
    this.keyCountMap = new HashMap<K, Integer>();
  }

  @Override
  public V put(K key, V value) {
    keyCountMap.put(key, keyCountMap.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
    return super.put(key, value);
  }

  public int fetchKeyCount(K key) {
    return keyCountMap.getOrDefault(key, 0);
  }
}
```

With this map, you can get your key insertion count by calling `fetchKeyCount` e.g.

```
  KeyCountMap<String, String> newMap = new KeyCountMap<>();
  newMap.put("aaa", "bbb");
  newMap.put("ccc", "ddd");
  newMap.put("eee", "fff");
  newMap.put("aaa", "bbb");
  System.out.println(newMap.fetchKeyCount("aaa"));
```

*EDIT*: Revised code per comments to remove a local LinkedHashMap field and added Java 8 `getOrDefault` method.

Comment: Right idea, but Java 8 makes this a lot less verbose with `getOrDefault`.

Comment: Our solutions are similar; I toyed with the idea of checking to see if the value was contained, but if it's not contained, it gets the cardinal value of 1 anyway.  Hence, Java 8 simplified it a great deal.

Comment: Yes I think using `getOrDefault` is better it also gives 0 instead of NPE for keys that don't exist, which makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
public final class PutCountingLinkedHashMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
    private final Map<K, Integer> putCounts = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public V put(final K key, final V value) {
        final int count = count(key);
        putCounts.put(key, count + 1);
        return super.put(key, value);
    }

    public int count(final K key) {
        return putCounts.getOrDefault(key, 0);
    }

    public int totalDuplicatePuts() {
      int total = 0;
        for (int i : putCounts.values()) {
            if (i > 1) total += i - 1;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PutCountingLinkedHashMap<String,String> map = new PutCountingLinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("aaa", "bbb");
map.put("ccc", "ddd");
map.put("eee", "fff");
map.put("aaa", "bbb");

int aaaCount = map.count("aaa"); //2
```

Additional work is required to decide what if anything to do with the counts on a `remove`, or `clear` etc.

> I am attempting to get a count of the number of times I've entered a duplicate key-value pair into the map

```
map.totalDuplicatePuts();
```

Comment: You were faster, now I have a very similar answer :-)

Comment: @vsnyc but why does yours have a `private LinkedHashMap<K,V> map;` field? Either it supports the interface `Map` and provides a backing field, or it inherits from `LinkedHashMap`, but not both.

Comment: I'll fix it, I was first building a wrapper and then extended `LinkedHashMap<K,V>` and mixed the two.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to write your custom "HashMap" class, it should implements the Comparable interface, then Override the put(k,v) method where you should use the custom compareTo(o) implementation before calling the super.put(k,v). Here is an example:

```
    public class MyMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> implements Comparable<Object>{

        @Override
        public V put(K key, V value){

            //Use your custom compareTo method to see if the key already exist, before the HasMap class does it.
            if(compareTo(key) != 0){
                super.put(key, value);
                return value;
            }else{
                //Do something else
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            //Implement your desire logic to compare
            //Test if the o object is an instance of desired class
            for(K item : this.keySet()){
                if(o.equals(item))
                    return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not a fan of `Comparable<Object>`.  Why does it need to be comparable at all?